# Cordova's FileTransfer Writing Error (Code 1)

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, file-transfer, cordova-plugins

I'm using Cordova 4.2.0 for Android.

I have some troubles to get [*FileTransfer plugin*](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer) work properly. I suppose that there is a writing error

```
exception:".myApp\/contentImages\/20150110220101.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)"
```

*filename* was previously tested and does not exist yet:

```
rootFS.getFile('.myApp/contentImages/'+file,{create:false},
    function(){
        console.log(file+' already exists');
    },
    function(error){
        console.log(file+" does not exist locally");
        console.log("Error #"+error.code);
        download(file);
    }
);
```

And here is the download function:

```
function download (filename){
    var localPath = rootFS.fullPath+'/.myApp/contentImages/'+filename;
    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
    fileTransfer.download(
        encodeURI('http://distantApp/contentImages/'+filename), // This file exists
        localPath,
        function(entry) {
            console.log("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
        },
        function (error) {
            console.log('download error: ' + error.code + ": "+error.exception+" ; source " + error.source+" ; target " + error.target);
        }
    );
}
```

What could be the problem?

***EDIT***
Code for `rootFS`

```
function onDeviceReady(){
    window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, function(){
        console.log("error requesting LocalFileSystem");
    });
}
function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    console.log("got filesystem: "+fileSystem.name); // displays "persistent"
    console.log(fileSystem.root.fullPath); // displays "/"
    window.rootFS = fileSystem.root;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to print the _localPath_ when you use it? It should be 'cdvfile://localhost/persistent/path/to/downloads/' and that path should be writable. You can check the writable paths from [File plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/doc/index.md#android-file-system-layout).

Comment: I think this is a good clue; I get this : `//.myApp/contentImages/image.jpg`. So I digged back to `rootFS` and I edited the question.

Comment: It seems that upgrading Cordova implied to replace `.fullPath` by `.toURL()`. I now get `file:///storage/emulated/0//.myApp/contentImages/image.jpg`.

Comment: @Yako: your path looks androidish

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem was caused by an upgrade of Cordova from a previous version.

The path of local files was not properly identified: `.fullPath`is now obsolete and should be replaced by `.toURL()`.

Comment: By now, PhoneGap should have really updated their documentation. I spent hours trying to figure this one out... and changing it to .toURL() fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is not with FileTransfer plugin, but the way you are trying to check if the file exists.

Looking here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/ you we'll see that accessing to a file which its immediately parent does not exist raise an exception:

> Inside the callback, we can call fs.root.getFile() with the name of the file to create. You can pass an absolute or relative path, but it must be valid. For instance, it is an error to attempt to create a file whose immediate parent does not exist.

I am wondering if the problem is that the parents of your file don't exist. In this case the folders .myapp and contentImages.

Comment: I think that the parent exists. I deleted the `contentImages` directory, and it is properly re-created. But you could have been right, as I did not paste this part of the code where the directory is created if it does not exist, and which leads to the `download()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Code 1 can be the access issue.
In my case there was a problem with file permissions.
If you use sdk version less then 29 (android 10) you have to force user to give read/write permission

add cordova-plugin-android-permissions in config.xml

```
const filesPermissions = (permissions) => [
 permissions.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
 permissions.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
];

const checkFilesPermissions = async () => {
  const { permissions } = window.cordova.plugins;
  return Promise.all(filesPermissions(permissions).map(permission => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => permissions.checkPermission(permission, resolve, reject));
  })).then(statuses => statuses.every(status => status.hasPermission));
};

const requestFilesPermissions = async () => {
    const { permissions } = window.cordova.plugins;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        permissions.requestPermissions(filesPermissions(permissions), resolve, reject);
  }).then(status => status.hasPermission);
};
```

// onClickHandler:

```
if (deviceService.isAndroidPlatform()) {
  try {
    let hasFilesPermissions = await checkFilesPermissions();
    if (!hasFilesPermissions) {
      hasFilesPermissions = await requestFilesPermissions();
    }
    if (!hasFilesPermissions) {
      throw new Error('There is no permissions to download files. Please enable it in system preferences');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    alert(error.message)
  }
}
```

// and then just download your file using cordova-plugin-file-transfer as usual

Note: you have to enable READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in your AndroidManifest.xml