# Phonegap File Download Issue

Tags: android, file, cordova, file-transfer

I'm trying to download remote file to my device. 
I'm using PhoneGap Build. Here is my code.

I tried every piece of code I found. When I click download button, nothing happens. On debug, no errors show up.

Where do I mistake?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.appRootDirName = "my_app";
  function onLoad(){
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
  }
  function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log("device is ready");
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
  }

  function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    console.log("filesystem got");
    window.fileSystem = fileSystem;
    fileSystem.root.getDirectory(window.appRootDirName, {
      create : true,
      exclusive : false
    }, dirReady, fail);
  }

  function dirReady(entry) {
    window.appRootDir = entry;
    console.log('application dir is ready');
  }

  function fail() {
    console.log('failed to get filesystem');
  }

  function downloadFile(url,fileName) {
    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
    var filePath = window.appRootDir.fullPath + "/" + fileName + ".txt";
    fileTransfer.download(url, filePath, function(entry) {
      alert("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
    }, function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }

$(document).ready(function(){
  .... some other code

  //on click download file
  $(document).on('click touchstart', '.download', function(e){
    e && e.preventDefault();

    var url = $(this).data('url');
    var title = $(this).data('title');

    downloadFile(url,title);

  });


});
</script>
```

Also config.xml

```
<gap:plugin name="com.coconutcenter.file-transfer" version="0.4.6" />

    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file" />
    <feature name="File">
           <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="FileTransfer">
          <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.filetransfer.FileTransfer" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Storage">
           <param value="org.apache.cordova.Storage" name="android-package"/>
</feature>
```

Error Code on .download method:

```
{"code":1,"source":"http://myurl.com/file.txt","target":"//my_app/file.txt","http_status":null,"body":null}
```

**Finally** I found the solution. As [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28136597/2185524) mentioned, I used `.toUrl()` insetad `fullPath`. So my downloadFile function would be;

```
  function downloadFile(url,fileName) {
    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
    var filePath = window.appRootDir.toUrl() + "/" + fileName + ".txt"; //here
    fileTransfer.download(url, filePath, function(entry) {
      alert("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
    }, function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Show the output of the error function

Comment: "On debug, no errors show up."

Comment: In your function downloadFile print the error function callbak like this console.log("error"+error).

Comment: this is error output `{"code":1,"source":"http://myurl.com/file.txt","target":"//my_app/file.txt","http_status":null,"body":null}`

Comment: **Finally** I found the solution. As  mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/a/28136597/2185524, I used `.toUrl()` insetad `fullPath`.

Comment: Might want to [self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) your question

Comment: I cant. Could someone post the solution and I mark it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28136597/2185524), I used `.toUrl()` instead `fullPath`